# How do I access a specific character in a font in html?

Tags: html, unicode, fonts

I am using @fontface to load in a character heavy font. There is a specific character I need from the font. But when I use unicode to access it, it displays the character in some other font (in some browsers). I know for sure the character is there.

I'd much rather have it match the document font. Any way to call it directly?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post a testable demonstration of the problem (HTML, CSS, with references to font files)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this A List Apart article. The pertinent CSS is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Kimberley";
  src: url(http://www.princexml.com/fonts/larabie/ »
  kimberle.ttf) format("truetype");
}
h1 { font-family: "Kimberley", sans-serif }
```

The above will work in Chrome/Safari/FireFox. As Paul D. Waite pointed out in the comments you can get it to work with IE if you convert the font to the EOT format.

The good news is that this seems to degrade gracefully in older browsers, so as long as you're aware and comfortable with the fact that not all users will see the same font, it's safe to use.

Comment: This apparently just illustrates `@font-face` without addressing the problem posed. The illustration is not very illustrative, since it uses a single font format only, against basic cross-browser requirements.